# Is It possible To develop windows phone 8 apps in windows phone SDK 8.1 with Visual studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

i have windows phone 8(Nokia lumia 525)

Is It possible To develop windows phone 8 apps in windows phone SDK 8.1 with Visual studio 2013?

Is there any problem like emulator problem, hosting app to windows store problem, windows azure for notification problem?

I am a fresher now only enter into development could you please solve my problem

Thank you so much

Comment: you could develop WP 8 apps for only Silverlight ones where you can choose the target platform Otherwise for the normal WinRT apps you cannot. If you really wanted to build the normal WinRT 8 apps you could go with VS 2012.

Comment: @anonshankar are you trying to tell it is support for windows phone apps in visual studio 2013 write? if you dont mind, could you please give me your contact like skype id, email id, phone no, i am fresher that y i am asking please dont mistake me.....

Comment: if you go to the profile here you could find out. Only in VS2013m you'll be able to target 8.1 apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Just select Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight) instead of Blank App (Windows Phone) and select the target windows phone OS version to 8.0. You're done. Refer the below image for more information.

[image]

Comment: i can't understand what you told i think you are tamil nadu, i am also tamil, i am a fresher could you please give me your