# Target Windows Phone 8 project on VS2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

When i create a new project in VS2013, automatically chose Windows Phone 8.1, how to change the target for Windows phone 8 only in visual Studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick a Windows Phone Silverlight template instead.  It should target 8.0 by default.

[image]

Comment: It targets 8.1 by default, but you get the option when creating the project to change to 8.0

Comment: Weird mine targets 8.0 by default, I have to manually change it to 8.1.  Universal Apps however target 8.1 by default.

Comment: Ah, right, I seem to have mixed those two up. (It really *should* target 8.1 by default, I'll have to go yell at the VS team for that)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903594/is-it-possible-to-develop-windows-phone-8-apps-in-windows-phone-sdk-8-1-with-vis