# Windows Phone 8.0 Project Template in VS2013.4

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

Is there a way to select Windows Phone 8.0 Project instead of 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013 when I want to create a Windows Phone Hub or Windows Phone Empty template?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the 8.0 SDK installed?

Comment: Yes. I can see Windows Store -> Windows Phone where there are only 8.1 templates are there. I can't see Windows Phone in the main list

Comment: added a screenshot. All of those items are loaded for Windows Phone 8.1 by default

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090201/target-windows-phone-8-project-on-vs2013/25090314#25090314  , you can change it in the properties menu of the project : "Target Windows OS Version"

Comment: target is not selectable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu on the screenshot, select Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight), next you will be shown a dialog to choose 8.1 or 8.0.

Comment: well, it's not asking :)