# Visual Studio support creation of Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

How do you make a Windows Phone 8.0 application with Visual Studio 2013?

[Windows Phone 8.0 Project Template in VS2013.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006416/windows-phone-8-0-project-template-in-vs2013-4)

I've followed the above but when I hit next it automatically makes a 8.1 project. It prompted me once on if I wanted 8.0 or 8.1, but that prompt no longer appears.

EDIT: Creating a Blank App (Windows Phone) only creates an 8.1 app. Creating a Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight) gives an option of 8.0 and 8.1.

What's going on?

Comment: Just to confirm: You are selecting the Silverlight templates right?

Comment: I'm selecting blank app (Windows Phone)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but I think you need to install the sdk for Windows 8 separately. You can side by side install multiple OS versions in your Visual Studio to have a look that how your app would respond in windows 8 environment.

You then also need the respective emulator image too.

After some googling i have found a link,  I personally haven't tried this ever but I hope this would be useful.

[Windows Phone SDK archives](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk)

This link contains the SDK for Windows 8 and 7.5 along with their respective emulator images.

Comment: I've already installed the Windows SDK. It prompted me once for 8.0 or 8.1 development and now it won't prompt anymore.

Comment: As a side note, it did install a windows phone IDE for development, but I thought it integrated into Visual Studio Express?